# Prove that if $\|A\|<1$, then $\|(I-A)^{-1}\|\geq {1\over1+\|A\|}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, geometric-series

Prove that if $\|A\|<1$, then $\|(I-A)^{-1}\|\geq {1\over1+\|A\|}$.

I'm not sure how to prove this result. I see feel like a geometric series is involved though. Any solutions or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Use $\Vert XY\Vert\leq \Vert X\Vert \cdot\Vert Y\Vert$ and a formula for $(I-A)^{-1}$.

Comment: Are you sure you've typed this correctly? As written, you could rewrite it as $1+\|A\| \ge \|I-A\|$. This is trivially true from the triangle inequality.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I believe OP probably typed this correctly -- this looks like the lemma Rudin uses to show that space of invertible linear operators is open.

Comment: @William My point is.. I think the inverse is supposed to be inside the norm.

Comment: Oh right - you said "as written"; I thought the trivial situation was when you changed the inequality, not before. Sorry about that oops.

Comment: @William No problem!

Comment: CameronWilliams and William are correct. If we consider the original statement it follows trivially from $\Vert I-A\Vert\leq\Vert I\Vert+\Vert A\Vert=1+\Vert A\Vert$. So the "hard" problem is to prove that $\Vert(I-A)^{-1}\Vert\geq\frac{1}{1+\Vert A\Vert}$.

Comment: I fixed it. The exponent was supposed to be in the norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that for $\|A\| < 1$, $(I-A)^{-1}$ is well-defined (prove this yourself if you have not done so yet) so we can talk about the inverse. Thus:

$$ I = (I-A)(I-A)^{-1}.$$

Here is a hint:

$$ 1 = \|I\| = \|(I-A)(I-A)^{-1}\|.$$

Try doing some basic norm manipulations to this. You need to *increase* the norm, not decrease it since you want a *lower* bound. (Luiz' comment might be useful here...)

The explicit formula for $(I-A)^{-1}$ is not super useful here (in my opinion) since that will give you an upper bound on the norm, not a lower bound.